# Incorrect timezone in Swift's DateInterval

Tags: swift, date, calendar, dateinterval

I want to store some data as a dictionary in my app relative to the date this data was created. It should look something like this:

```
// hours
[ 17:00 - 18:00 : 34.5,
  18:00 - 19:00 : 41.2,
... ]

// days
[ 2017-11-19 - 2017-11-20 : 37.9,
  2017-11-20 - 2017-11-21 : 31.1,
... ]
```

A `DateInterval` structure seems to be a perfect candidate for a key in this dictionary. But as I ran some basic tests I found that while date created with `Date()` init represents correct information on a given moment in time, the `DateInterval` structure from `Calendar.current` appears to be defaulting to GMT+0 as a timezone, so I'm getting following output:

```
let date = Date() //outputs "Nov 20, 2017 at 10:32 PM"
let hourInterval = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .hour, for: date)
//outputs: 2017-11-20 20:00:00 +0000 to 2017-11-20 21:00:00 +0000
```

So it's 2 hours off my/user's timezone. What is the correct way to use `DateInterval` so it doesn't shift in timezones?

Comment: did you check [converting date between timezones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641982/converting-date-between-timezones-swift)

Comment: That is just how the interval is *printed* (using GMT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal structure of dates in iOS is always GMT.  What you're seeing is the string representation.  The internal dates are still consistent with one another.  Consider this playground code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import XCTest
import PlaygroundSupport


let fourHours:Double = -1 * 60 * 60 * 4
var newDate = Date()
let oldDate = Date(timeInterval: fourHours, since: newDate)
let interval = DateInterval(start: oldDate, end: newDate)

let hourInterval = Calendar.current.dateInterval(of: .hour, for: newDate)
```

The output looks like this:

[image: result]

Even though the dates are show as local time (EST) the printable representation is in GMT.  The times are offset though, so 'Nov 20, 2017 at 4:14 PM EST' is equivalent to '2017-11-20 21:14:09 +0000'.  You can always retrieve the original date objects from the DateInterval with

```
hourInterval?.start
hourInterval?.end
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing the concept)) Just got confused because string representations will be used to display information in charts and I was afraid  all components would get messed up.